# What does the plot of the universe's Entropy versus Time starting from the big bang look like?

Tags: entropy, time, big-bang

What does the plot of the entire universe's Entropy versus Time starting from the big bang look like?

Is it even possible to create such a figure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entropy is going to increase as time increases. The entropy was at zero or at least it is meaningful to put it at zero. As time increases the disorder increases(this happens initially due to the expansion of the universe) as this results in the dispersion of energy. Now the entropy is going to be high but it still not high enough. Thermal equilibrium is when it is said that entropy is at its highest.

Comment: Do we know the value of that maximum?

Comment: I do not know about the value but it must be a huge value for entropy of the total universe as the maximum entropy. However there might not even be a highest entropy as thermal equilibrium may be just another point where we could just assign a zero. However they just consider thermal equilibrium as highest entropy. If I were to assign a number it would be like 10^100 and even this is probably an over simplification. It might be way higher.